# Growing bool[] as bits in (specific linear fashion != >> || <<)

Tags: c#

I'm currently working with genetic algorithms and am trying to improve my mutations. Currently I'm using a rather random way of mutating and i want to implement a linear, ~predictable locus mutation model.

My chromosomes are represented as a BitString class which internally uses a flat bool[] to store the locuses. Depending on the type of data i encode in a  chromosome a locus can be n*2 bits long. To give some context here's my Mutation method:

```
internal static BitString Mutate(BitString chromosome, float mutationRate)
{
  var newChromosome = new BitString(chromosome);
  int locusLength = chromosome.LocusLength;
  int numLocuses = chromosome.Length / locusLength;

  float locusMutationRate = mutationRate * 0.25;

  for (int l = 0; l < numLocuses; l++)
  {
    bool[] oldLocus = chromosome[l * locusLength, locusLength];
    bool mutateThis = rnd.NextDouble() <= locusMutationRate;

    if (mutateThis)
    {
      bool[] newlocus = new bool[1]; // fail this one on purpose since !=n*2

      while (!BitString.IsValidLocus(newlocus, chromosome.Type, true))
      {
        newlocus = new bool[locusLength];

        int mutationIndex = rnd.Next(locusLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < locusLength; i++)
        {
          if (i == mutationIndex)
            newlocus[i] = !oldLocus[i];
          else
            newlocus[i] = oldLocus[i];
        }
      }

      newChromosome[l * locusLength, locusLength] = newlocus;
    }
  }

  return newChromosome;
}
```

As you can see here:

```
    int mutationIndex = rnd.Next(locusLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < locusLength; i++)
    {
      if (i == mutationIndex)
        newlocus[i] = !oldLocus[i];
      else
        newlocus[i] = oldLocus[i];
    }
```

the mutation is purely random

Now for the purposes of this question let's assume that I'm encoding an ASCII string, so each locus will be bool[8] bits. For the sake of readability I'll format them as ints

oldLocus would be

```
bool[] {10000000}
```

growing oldLocus should give

```
bool[] {01000000}
```

shrinking oldLocus should give

```
bool[] {00000000}
```

---

now let's say oldLocus is

```
bool[] {11100000}
```

growing oldLocus should give

```
bool[] {00010000}
```

shrinking oldLocus should give

```
bool[] {01100000}
```

shrinking that again should give

```
bool[] {10100000}
```

shrinking that again..

```
bool[] {00100000}
```

and again

```
bool[] {11000000}
```

So you see the kind of pro/re-gression I'm after. Since the locuses can be any length (n*2) depending on the dataType the encode I can't cheat my way through that using bytes or ints to grow/shrink them. I should also not that locus will never change it's length throughout it's entire lifetime since it always encodes the same valueType.

I've banged my head against trying to find a simple and performant solution to this problem but couldn't come up with anything so I could use some help.
If you need more details let me know.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to just use a List<bool> instead so that it can grow/shrink without making a new fixed-length bool[]?

Comment: the lenth of a locus isn't supposed to change, that will stay const; what's supposed to "grow"/"shrink" is the "values" as per the pro/reGression samples i wrote up

Comment: ASCII is a **7 bit** encoding.

Comment: Could you make use of the [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) class that's built into C#? Admittedly I'm no expert in this stuff, but I used to use `bool[]`s a lot until I learned about that class.

Answer (score 0):

*I can't cheat my way through that using bytes or ints to grow/shrink them*

What if you used the BigInteger structure in System.Numerics?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx